# PHP Class throws an error, what is wrong

Tags: php, class

I have the class.

```
Class User {

    private $_name;
    private $_email;

    public static function factory() {
        return new __CLASS__;
    }

    public function test() {

    }
}
```

and when i make a static method call using the syntax below.

```
User::factory();
```

it throws me following syntax error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS_C in htdocs/test/index.php on line 8
```

the error is being thrown because the Static factory() method is unable to create the object during the static method call.

and when i change the magic constant `__CLASSS__` to the name of the current class i.e to `User` then it works.

what am i missing?

Comment: Why don't you return `self` or `$this`? Do you need an new instance of the object?

Comment: yes, i need to create new instance of the object everytime i make call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
Class User {

    private $_name;
    private $_email;

    public static function factory() {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            return new $class;
    }

    public function test() {

    }
}
```

Comment: that of course works, that's not the point, i don't want to create the object that way.

Comment: You are trying to create a dynamic return?

Comment: hehe, i was missing this trick :), by the way it should be `return new $class;` not `return new $class();`

Comment: you are correct, but both works since it's a class/object. If you want to pas parameters then you will have to use (). In this case, you don't need.

Answer (score 8):

Not really sure why your example doesn't works. But what *does* work is:

```
public static function factory()
{
    return new self();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$class = __CLASS__;
return new $class;
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(, throws the following error `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: sorry, my bad, I edited my answer, this time it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you return `self` or `$this`?

Check out the singleton patterns: http://www.phpbar.de/w/Singleton and http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.patterns.php

Other solution would be

```
return clone $this;
```

Comment: You realize you posted a German-language site in the first link?